# Is it possible to offer failover even using DNS round robin?

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, ping, google, round-robin

A company X has five ips to a given service.

```
$ host www.example.com.br
www.example.com.br has address 13.194.4.159
www.example.com.br has address 13.194.4.152
www.example.com.br has address 13.194.4.151
www.example.com.br has address 13.194.4.143
www.example.com.br has IPv6 address 2190:3f0:4004:810::100f
```

And they're using DNS with round robin method. Is it possible to offer a failover in this solution?

*(since I cant answer my question)* **Yes, it is**. If each of these ips point to a failover LB.
[image: floating ip]

- actually both LB have access to all cluster, not just a set of nodes as it is in the image above.

Comment: Not really round robin dns just a anycast/unicast dns . he resolve the nearest google "pop" .

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because obviously you are not working for Google and therefore are not tasked with finding faults in their infrastructure, meaning you have no actual problem to solve. Please read the [help].

Comment: It's really not a problem to be solved, it is a question to be answered. Curiosity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow - you know this site isn't for beginners right? we make that very clear when you sign up.

Anyway - of course Google use 'something with failover', anyone professional would. And yes it appears to be some form of load-balancing, it could be round-robin but it's more likely to be a lot smarter than that, including the use of sticky-sessions though that's not what they'll use for DNS.

And yes, DNS caching on your side will be throwing things, just drop your DNS cache between each attempt. Oh and what are you trying to do here, if you're looking to find fault in their front-end systems with the skill level you've demonstrated you may be some time.

Comment: I'm just wanting to know how things works. You should be less rude "skill level you've demonstrated you may be some time" && "you know this site isn't for beginners right?". Even though I don't see where you took these conclusions.

Comment: @leandromoreira Because this site is not for beguinners and this is a very basic question. And the answer to your massively-rewritten question is to look at Cisco GSS's.

Comment: okay, I got it, thanks! Just in case, I wasn't looking for fault/flaw, I was really trying to understand.